# Find a FolderName\file.name combination(s) recursively in a batch file and return the full path(s)

Tags: batch-file, recursion, search, design-patterns, directory

I'm looking to find a specific file name within a specific folder name in a directory recursively and return the full path if there is a match or multiple matches. I'm looking for a pattern search that can possibly even use a 3 part lookup i.e (folderA\folderB\file.name). But 2 will do for now. So far my efforts have brought me to this. But it is terribly slow. *16+ seconds to find the match.*

```
   ::recursively find foldername\file.name combination

   cd C:\searchFolder
   for /r %a in (FolderName) do @if exist "%~fa\file.name" echo %~fa
```

I only need to venture about 2 to 4 levels deep and pull up the first folder\file.ext match and grab the full path. Is there a faster way to do this, with maybe the dir command or an exclusion list or even a true *folder\file pattern search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first clarify the task with an example folder structure and a file with name `file.name` in each subfolder of `C:\SearchFolder`:

```
C:\SearchFolder
├───FolderA
│   │   file.name
│   │   
│   ├───FolderA
│   │   │   file.name
│   │   │   
│   │   ├───FolderA
│   │   │   │   file.name
│   │   │   │   
│   │   │   ├───FolderA
│   │   │   │       file.name
│   │   │   │       
│   │   │   └───FolderB
│   │   │           file.name
│   │   │           
│   │   └───FolderB
│   │       │   file.name
│   │       │   
│   │       ├───FolderA
│   │       │       file.name
│   │       │       
│   │       └───FolderB
│   │               file.name
│   │               
│   └───FolderB
│       │   file.name
│       │   
│       ├───FolderA
│       │   │   file.name
│       │   │   
│       │   ├───FolderA
│       │   │       file.name
│       │   │       
│       │   └───FolderB
│       │           file.name
│       │           
│       └───FolderB
│           │   file.name
│           │   
│           ├───FolderA
│           │       file.name
│           │       
│           └───FolderB
│                   file.name
│                   
└───FolderB
    │   file.name
    │   
    ├───FolderA
    │   │   file.name
    │   │   
    │   ├───FolderA
    │   │   │   file.name
    │   │   │   
    │   │   ├───FolderA
    │   │   │       file.name
    │   │   │       
    │   │   └───FolderB
    │   │           file.name
    │   │           
    │   └───FolderB
    │       │   file.name
    │       │   
    │       ├───FolderA
    │       │       file.name
    │       │       
    │       └───FolderB
    │               file.name
    │               
    └───FolderB
        │   file.name
        │   
        ├───FolderA
        │   │   file.name
        │   │   
        │   ├───FolderA
        │   │       file.name
        │   │       
        │   └───FolderB
        │           file.name
        │           
        └───FolderB
            │   file.name
            │   
            ├───FolderA
            │       file.name
            │       
            └───FolderB
                    file.name
```

That folder structure with the files can be created using:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseFolder=C:\SearchFolder"
for %%G in (A B) do (
    for %%H in (A B) do (
        for %%I in (A B) do (
            for %%J in (A B) do (
                md "%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J"
                echo "%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J">"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J\file.name"
            )
            echo "%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I">"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\file.name"
        )
        echo "%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H">"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\file.name"
    )
    echo "%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G">"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\file.name"
)
endlocal
```

The example structure is output on running `tree /F C:\SearchFolder` in a Windows command prompt window.

There should be searched for files with name `file.name` in just the first three subfolder levels of `C:\SearchFolder` and the found files with that name must have a path ending with `FolderA\FolderB\`.

That can be done using the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseFolder=C:\SearchFolder"
set "FolderName1=FolderA"
set "FolderName2=FolderB"
set "FileName=file.name"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%BaseFolder%" /AD /B 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('dir "%BaseFolder%\%%I\%FolderName1%\%FolderName2%\%FileName%" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do echo "%BaseFolder%\%%G\%FolderName1%\%FolderName2%\%FileName%"
)
for /F "delims=" %%J in ('dir "%BaseFolder%\%FolderName1%\%FolderName2%\%FileName%" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do echo "%BaseFolder%\%FolderName1%\%FolderName2%\%FileName%"
endlocal
```

The output is:

```
"C:\SearchFolder\FolderA\FolderA\FolderB\file.name"
"C:\SearchFolder\FolderB\FolderA\FolderB\file.name"
"C:\SearchFolder\FolderA\FolderB\file.name"
```

So there are just three **FOR** commands necessary to search for file `file.name` in the thirst three subfolders of `C:\SearchFolder` being stored in a folder with name `FolderB` with is inside a folder with name `FolderA`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `tree /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>` and `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command lines to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command lines before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

PS: `rd /Q /S C:\SearchFolder` deletes the entire example folder structure.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  This works and I have a much better understanding of the 'for' loop parameters now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to limit the levels, as mentioned in your question, *(but not clarified)*, perhaps using `Robocopy.exe` will allow you to drill down only the required number of levels too.

As a quick example, use the first script below to create your test directory structure:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "BaseFolder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\SearchFolder"
For %%G In (A B) Do (
    For %%H In (A B) Do (
        For %%I In (A B) Do (
            For %%J In (A B) Do (
                For %%K In (A B) Do (
                    For %%L In (A B) Do (
                        MD "%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J\Folder%%K\Folder%%L"
                        CD.>"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J\Folder%%K\Folder%%L\file.name"
                    )
                    CD.>"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J\Folder%%K\file.name"
                )
                CD.>"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\Folder%%J\file.name"
            )
            CD.>"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\Folder%%I\file.name"
        )
        CD.>"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\Folder%%H\file.name"
    )
    CD.>"%BaseFolder%\Folder%%G\file.name"
)
```

Then use the following script to list your found paths:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "BaseFolder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\SearchFolder"
Set "FolderName1=FolderA"
Set "FolderName2=FolderB"
Set "FileName=file.name"

For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe
 "%BaseFolder%" "Null" "%FileName%" /FP /L /LEV:5 /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /S ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RI "\\%FolderName1%\\%FolderName2%\\%FileName%$"
') Do Echo %%G
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```